# Including pictures in subdirectories with standalone package

Tags: external-files, standalone

After using `standalone` package extensively, I ran into one problem, which I cannot solve. The problem is that I need to include a TikZ picture in main files subdirectory. What is more I want to build it with standalone `mode = buildnew`. Consider the following filetree:

```
/mwe.tex
/sub/mwefig.tex
```

File `mwe.tex` contains the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\standaloneconfig{mode=buildnew}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
Time is money!

\includestandalone{sub/mwefig}

\end{document}
```

And the file `mwefig.tex` contains the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

After execution of `mwe.tex` I would expect `mwefig.tex` to be built, which would result in `mwefig.pdf` file created in `/sub/` directory, which could then be used for later compilations.

What I rather get is a warning: `Package standalone Warning: Graphic 'sub/mwefig.pdf' could not be build.` Even though, the main PDF is produced containing the required graphics.

I also noticed, the `mwefig.pdf` file is actually created, however in a separate directory and with different name:

```
/sub'/mwefig'.pdf
```

So after compilation I have the following filetree (excluding aux and log files):

```
/mwe.tex
/mwe.pdf
/sub/mwefig.tex
/sub'/mwefig'.pdf
```

I am probably using something wrong, so if anyone could give any hints on how to solve this problem I would be very grateful. (Note: `--enable-write18` is enabled, MikTex 2.9)

Comment: `standalone` uses quotes around the file name to avoid issues with potential spaces and other special characters in them. However, Windows requires double quotes here but Linux (my main OS) requires single quotes. There is a test built in to use the correct quotes for the users OS. Could you check the version of `standalone`. It should be fixed in v1.1 and later. See the bug report: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issue/2/trouble-with-conversion

Comment: @MartinScharrer, thank You for replying. By building the document in the link you specified, I get a log file, which states that the current version of `standalone` is v1.1b. (The log file can be seen [Test Log](http://txtup.co/DUlo9)). Also, could you provide an example of `quote` option usage. I have tried including `\standaloneconfig{convert={quote={"}}}` in either mwefig.tex and mwe.tex preamble. However upon compiling, an error is produced: `! Package xkeyval Error: convert' undefined in families standalone.sty'.`.

Comment: Ok, it seems that migrating from v1.1b to v1.2 solved the problem. I have probably used wrong syntax in v1.1b.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, as Karolis, I also get this error using v1.1b which can not be fixed by the `convert{quote{=}}}` trick. 
Since v1.2 is not in the CTAN archive I'm not much for using it, so I tried by overriding the build setting `latexoptions` byt adding `build={latexoptions={-interaction=batchmode -shell-escape -jobname " \\buildjobname "}}` to the package options. This however, ends in a runaway argument. Can you provide a work-around?

Comment: @Juhl: v1.2 isn't released yet. I will have a look at this problem in the next way as soon I find some time. About your `latexoptions` code: the double backslash is wrong. Try it with `\noexpand\buildjobname` if you are using it as class option. Note that there is also a config file as explained by the manual.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Even with `\noexpand` I get two errors: `undefined control sequence...\buildjobname` and `unknown option 'build' for package 'standalone'`.
Also tried using `\standaloneconfig`, but that just gives an error `'build'/'latexoptions' undefined in families 'standalone.sty'`. Not sure how to use this config file correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be solved by version 1.1b:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{mode=buildnew}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Documents/test_standalone_slave.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
That's it!
\includestandalone{Documents/test_standalone_slave}
\end{document}
```

The only issue that still appears to me is while using an external style sheet by using `\input{macros.tex}` in the slave's preamble.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I have to ask:

"The only issue that still appears to me is while using an external style sheet by using \input{macros.tex} in the slave's preamble."

Has this been solved somehow?