# LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode with \pgfplotstableread in a standalone picture

Tags: pgfplots

`document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

`plot.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
  X Y
  1 2
  3 4
}\table

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table {\table};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile with:

```
pdflatex document.tex
```

And I obtain:

```
(./plot.tex

! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14     \addplot table {\table};

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.14     \addplot table {\table};

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on document.log.
```

The standalone file compiles just fine, I only get that error if I try to include it in another document. Why does this happen and what are my options here?

Comment: It works with plot.tex containing just the following: `\pgfplotstableread{
  X Y
  1 2
  3 4
}\table
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table {\table};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: [Best practice to include (standalone precompiled) graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152247/134144)  and [How to externalize TikZ pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482557/134144)  might also be interesting.

Comment: Try to to give it some other name. ´\table` is already defined in latex and move the \pgfplotstableread behind \begin{document}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer changing to `\mytable` I get: `Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotstableread@filename ->\mytable`

Comment: @leandriis yes but I'd like to also render the `plot.tex` file alone. Let me take a look at those links...

Comment: yes as I added: move the definition to the document body.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry I didn't see the edit, that works thanks! Feel free to post the answer (FYI there is no need to rename `\table` in this example).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523727/latex-error-not-in-outer-par-mode-with-pgfplotstableread-in-a-standalone-pictu?noredirect=1#comment1324869_523727), the solution is to move `\pgfplotstableread` inside `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfplotstableread{
  X Y
  1 2
  3 4
}\table
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table {\table};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```